# How to set defualt processor on IDA

Tags: ida

I open binary file with IDA and each time I need to choose my processor.(by default I see different processor than I need)

How can I choose default processor(cpu) that each time will be choosen when I open file with IDA?

Comment: I didn't do it myself, but I think that you can either run IDA with -p option or fix cfg/ida.cfg file DEFAULT_PROCESSOR section.

Answer (score 3):

I checked it for ida 7.1. The simplest way is fix cfg/ida.cfg file DEFAULT_PROCESSOR section as follows:

Find `DEFAULT_PROCESSOR = {` clause in the file and replace the "" related to "*" to processor that you need.

```
DEFAULT_PROCESSOR = {
/* Extension    Processor */
  "com" :       ""                      // IDA will try the specified
  "exe" :       ""                      // extensions if no extension is
  "dll" :       ""                      // given.
  "drv" :       ""
  "sys" :       ""
  "bin" :       ""                      // Empty processor means the default processor
  "ovl" :       ""
  "ovr" :       ""
  "ov?" :       ""
  "nlm" :       ""
  "lan" :       ""
  "dsk" :       ""
  "obj" :       ""
  "prc" :       "68000"                 // PalmPilot programs
  "axf" :       "arm"
  "h68" :       "68000"                 // MC68000 for *.H68 files
  "i51" :       "8051"                  // i8051   for *.I51 files
  "sav" :       "pdp11"                 // PDP-11  for *.SAV files
  "rom" :       "z80"                   // Z80     for *.ROM files
  "cla*":       "java"
  "s19":        "6811"
  "epoc":       "arm"
  "o":          ""
  "*":          "put the name of your processor here"                      // Default processor
}
```

If you want your default processor to be arm just put arm inside the corresponding quotes as follows:

```
    "*":          "arm"                      // Default processor
```

This is, by the way, exact quote from my configuration.

In addition you can run IDA with -p option.

Documentation about -p and other command line switches is [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml).
Documentation about processor types is [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/618.shtml).

Comment: I not get you,  how can I put on `cfg/ida.cfg` that default processot will be arm ?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I wasn't so clear , there is some arm that I can select when I open ida (little/big indiand and more of that) where I can see all the list of processor that I can write on ` "*"`

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/618.shtml